# Get username object without requesting it after authentication? (Node & express.js)

Tags: node.js, express, mongodb-query, jwt

I'm making a Node backend using `express` (also using `bcrypt` for password hashing and `jsonwebtoken` for authorization). My requests are in separate files and they all use `module.exports`. I have this login request that is in a file called `login.js`:

```
router.post("/account/login", async (req, res) => {

    // User object
    const user = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    // Get user name only
    const username = {
        username: req.body.username
    };

    // Create a new JWT token
    const token = jwt.sign(username, secret);

    // Get username as a string
    const usernameString = JSON.stringify(user.username);

    // Get hashed password from the collection
    const hashedPassword = await logincollection.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

    // Search for matching login credentials
    await logincollection.findOne(username, (err, result) => {

        // If username was not found, return code 400
        if (result == null) {
            res.status(400).send();
        }

        // Proceed if username was found
        else {

            // If no token was given, return code 401
            if (!token) {
                res.status(401).send();
            }

            // Verify the given JWT token
            jwt.verify(token, secret, (err, decoded) => {

                // If verification failed, return code 500
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).send();
                }

            })

            // Use bcrypt to compare the passwords and authenticate login
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, hashedPassword.password).then(match => {

                // If the credentials match
                if (match) {

                    // Insert the token into a cookie
                    res.cookie("token", token, { httpOnly: true });

                    // Return code 200
                    res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token });

                    // Log to console when user logs in
                    console.log("User " + usernameString + " logged in");

                }

                // If the credentials do not match
                else {

                    // Return code 404
                    res.status(400).send();

                }

            // If comparing fails
            }).catch(error => {

                // Return code 500
                res.status(500).send();

            })

        }

    })

})
```

Every user has their own collection in a MongoDB database that is created, when the account is created. These collections are named after the username, since usernames are unique here. In this `load.js` file I have a request that loads all the objects in the collection:

```
router.post("/note/load", async (req, res) => {

    // User object
    const username = {
        username: req.body.username
    };

    // Get usercollection depending on username
    const usercollection = userdb.collection(JSON.stringify(username));

    // Load the notes
    const loadNote = await usercollection.find().toArray();

    // Return code 200 and sendObject
    res.status(200).send(loadNote);

})
```

Obviously, the code above will result in an error, because the username is not given in the request. Is there a way to pass the username to any request, when needed? Or can I use JWT for this, and if so, how? I have tried storing usernames in a variable, but that doesn't work, since the variable gets overwritten, when two users are logged in at the same time.

PS. The title is poor, because I don't know how to put this shortly. If you have any suggestions or corrections regarding the question or the title, please comment below.

Comment: add a middleware that checks the token and then places fetched user if token is good into req.user and then `next()`'s to the middleware, then req.user will be populated, `router.post("/note/load", checkToken, async (req, res) => {`, else throw error and let error handler respond.

Comment: yes where are you authenticating the requests after they log in?  Are you passing up a session cookie or something else?  IN any case as Lawrence Cherone mentions wherever (in middleware) you authenticate APIs you can attach the user context to the request (in `req`) and access it in the routes afterwards.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone where exactly should I place the middleware? To the login request?

Comment: you place it on routes which need protecting or need access to the user, so not login. logins job is to issue out tokens

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `places fetched user if token is good into req.user` how do I get the fetched user on a request where the user object is not given?

Comment: you need to a do little more research on how jwt works. if you need the user object then your client side code needs send the jwt (it should be via a cookie like in your code but your ajax client code must be setup to send cookies) and you need a middleware serverside to validate and decode the token and then load the user. if you dont send the token then you cant get the user, jwt is not sessions its stateless meaning the token is the session so it needs sending and any route which you need to protect you add the middleware, like in my first comment

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks, I think I got it now. The problem was that I didn't know that the decoded token has the username in it.